# find document that had specific number fields mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[image: my documents]

Is this possible in mongodb to select only document that had 49 fields? So i select document that had an `_id: ObjectId("5a4ad9c298767555dde892a2")` then had 49 fields in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to get all fields from `$$ROOT` object as an array of keys and values. Then you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get the length of that array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { numberOfFields: { $size: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } }
    },
    {
        $match: { numberOfFields: 49 }
    }
])
```

Comment: `// what if i just select  select document that had 49 fields? `

edit: Got it, nice 

Comment: The query didnot work on fled that only have 26 fields below, I updated the Image

Comment: I guess because tool shows you `_id` + `26` fields, while this code counts all the fields including _id. Could you try `27` in your condition ?

Comment: It works actually sorry, The DB are just to big and comes up with error when i tried access it with robomongo, when use terminal it works fine. thanks 